# iphone: Scale the image in table cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, size, image-scaling

I am using a UITableViewCellStyleSubTitle. I am trying to add thumbnails to my table cells.
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit does not seem to work for reasons unknown. I have seen a lot of answers in stack overflow for similar kind of questions. If i crop the image using drawInRect it works, like this

```
[thumbnail drawInRect:thumbnailRect];
UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

But what i am trying to achieve should not need me to do this. I am only trying to scale the image and not crop it. 
So setting the content mode to "UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit" for the imageview of the default cell should work.. but it does not.

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Complete logic for setting thumbnails.. fPath is the path to image

```
UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fPath];
[cell.imageView setImage:thumbnail];
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Try subclussin UITableViewCell or create UIImageView in code and add it to cell's contentView.

Comment: that would work.. but is it not a overhead not necessary for what i am trying to achieve.. ? i want a standard cell ..

Answer (score 0):

I found out that drawInRect stretches the original image if the size is lower or croppes it if it is bigger.

This article will help you to prepare a thumbnail of your image
http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

It has several useful UIImage classes extentions:
* UIImage+Resize
* UIImage+Alpha
* UIImage+RoundedCorner

Example Usage:

> UIImage *imageThumb = [YourImage thumbnailImage:70 transparentBorder:0 cornerRadius:10 interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];

and then you can use drawInRect method. If the image is not rectangle - the image will crop the bigger side and take the middle of the image

Hope this answer will guide you.